# How to clear an array in Julia

Tags: julia

I have an array representing image metadata that I want to clear out. Currently, I use the `empty!()` function but it is throwing an error because I think it needs to be a dictionary and I have an array so I am looking for an alternate way to clear the Array.

For reference, here is the type I am working with:

```
Array{ImageMetadata.ImageMeta{ColorTypes.Gray{FixedPointNumbers.Normed{UInt8,8}},2,Array{ColorTypes.Gray{FixedPointNumbers.Normed{UInt8,8}},2},P} where P<:AbstractDict{Symbol,Any},1}
```

Comment: Please include an instance of the array, not just a type.
Or code that will generate an instance.

and then a copy of the actual error message when you call `empty!`

Comment: Edit this to include a small example of what you have and what you want and I'm sure it'll get reopened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "clear", but in general you can use `fill!` to fill the array with a value of your choice.

However, if your question is to make an array filled with some values to be set to have `#undef` in its entries (if its `eltype` allows for it), then I do not know of a method to make this. You can use `similar` to create a new array that will have the same shape and be uninitialized.

Answer (score 9):

`empty!` shouldn't be throwing an error:

```
julia> x = rand(10);

julia> empty!(x)
0-element Array{Float64,1}
```

Would be useful to know what error you're actually seeing.

Comment: `empty!` works only for vectors, it does not work for arrays of higher dimension.

Comment: Right, but `Array{ImageMetadata.ImageMeta{ColorTypes.Gray{FixedPointNumbers.Normed{UInt8,8}},2,Array{ColorTypes.Gray{FixedPointNumbers.Normed{UInt8,8}},2},P} where P<:AbstractDict{Symbol,Any},1}` is a `Vector`.

Comment: Ah - indeed in this case. I thought `where` was outside `Array` and got confused by `2` earlier in the line.

Comment: So it actually works for 2 of the 6 objects. the latter 6 are actuall of type `Array{ColorTypes.RGB{FixedPointNumbers.Normed{UInt8,8}},2}` so the first 2 clear fine using `empty!()` but the latter 4 do not.

Comment: Right, that's consistent with Bogumił's comment then. Why do you want to "clear" the content and what do you expect to happen for the multi-dim arrays?